# installing DPDK on Ubuntu 18.04 and intel XL710

Tags: driver, nic, dpdk, usrp

I'm trying to make DPDK work on my machine without success; My machine is running Ubuntu 18.04 and the NIC I'm trying to bind is an Intel XL710. I'm completely new to DPDK and not an expert on linux.

*Additional context: I need DPDK in order to get more bandwidth when using a USRP SDR (Software Defined Radio), that has this capability.*

What I've done so far:

- Added `default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=8` to the grub config
- Cloned and compiled DPDK 19, installed with `make install`. Result: `Installation in /usr/local/ complete`
- get the status of the devices and drivers using `./dpdk-devbind.py -s`. The relevant line I get from this command is: `0000:02:00.0 'Ethernet Controller XL710 for 40GbE QSFP+ 1583' if=enp2s0f0 drv=i40e unused=`

When I try to bind the device (even if it is already binded? shouldn't I get a different driver/option for that?) using `sudo ./dpdk-devbind.py -b i40e 0000:02:00.0` I get:

```
Warning: no supported DPDK kernel modules are loaded
Notice: 0000:02:00.0 already bound to driver i40e, skipping
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before binding the `i40e` NIC to DPDK PMD driver, you need to load `uio` or `vfio` Linux driver as shown below:

```
modprobe uio
insmod ./x86_64-native-linux-gcc/kmod/igb_uio.ko
```

or

```
modprobe vfio-pci
```

Take a look at [link](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html) to know why we should load kernel module before ports are bind to DPDK.

Comment: Simply restarting the machine and using modprobe did the trick. Simple and effective. Thanks. Now: the fact that I still cannot use the DPDK because many peripherals are on the same iommu group is an other thing, I’ll probably post an other question before patching my kernel.